# Unexpected behaviour in LDAP query written in Perl

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, perlscript

I'm trying to implement a simple LDAP query in Perl. I want to retrieve the 'dc' attribute from all the 'dnsZone' objects from the domain.
I first wrote it using dsquery and it works perfectly:

```
dsquery * "DC=iii,DC=hogent,DC=be" -attr dc -scope subtree -filter "(objectClass=dnsZone)"
```

Now when I try to implement this in Perl, I receive the following error when I just query for the 'dc' attribute. When I query for the 'dc' and the 'name' attribute (which look the same) I don't have problems.

> OLE exception from "ADODB.Fields":
>
> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal.

I was thinking in the direction of the property cache, maybe the property is not yet available. But I don't know how i should refresh the property cache using an LDAP query. Maybe it has a getInfoEx([...], 0) variant?

```
my $rootDSE = bind_object('RootDSE');

my $base = bind_object($rootDSE->Get('defaultNamingContext'))->{ADsPath};
my $filter = "(objectClass=dnsZone)";
my $attrs = 'dc'; #No error when i change this into 'dc,name'
my $scope = 'subTree';

my $connection = Win32::OLE->CreateObject('ADODB.Connection');
   $connection->{Provider} = 'ADsDSOObject';
   $connection->Open();

my $command = Win32::OLE->CreateObject('ADODB.Command');
   $command->{ActiveConnection} = $connection;
   $command->{CommandText} = "<$base>;$filter;$attrs;$scope;";

my $resultSet = $command->Execute();

until($resultSet->{EOF}) {
    my $fields = $resultSet->{Fields};
    print $fields->{dc}->{Value}."\n";
    $resultSet->MoveNext();
}
```

Does someone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue can occur with ldap client failing to lookup results when a query matches one entry (or more) that does not have *any* of the requested attributes.

Removing attributes from the query and using dc as a *filter* may help to check whether or not you are in that situation:

- remove `$attrs` from the query, run the query and check the results count.
- make the filter match only entries having a dc: `"(&(objectClass=dnsZone)(dc=*))"`, run the query (no $attrs) and check the results count.
- compare the results count.

If the 2nd query brings fewer results than the previous one, it means the original query matches entries that have no `dc` (error when requesting `dc` only, no error with both attributes).

That also means the objectClass `dnsZone` does not make mandatory the `DomainComponent` attribute as you might expect when using it as a filter to read dc's.